# Magento 2 - How to unset a checkout step by checking a quote item option value?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2

I have added a custom checkout step in magento 2. How can i remove that specific step in one page checkout by checking quote item specific option value ?

I can not specify condition in xml file, Is there any way that I can override a one page checkout block and do that there ?

Please suggest!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<action method="unsetElement"><argument name="name" xsi:type="string" helper="yourmodule/helper/methodname" /></action>
```

Thanks should be placed under parent block of block that you are going to remove.

Inside the method of helper put your business logic and finally return a block string . If you want to remove any block then block name will be return as string.